# How to set 7-digit precision after the floating point

Tags: c#, precision

Example that calculates area of trapezoid

```
Input 5, 7, 12, Output 72.0000000
Input 8.5, 4.3, 2.7, Output 49.5000000
Input 100, 200, 300,    Output 45000.0000000
Input 5, 7, 12, Output 72.0000000
Input 0.222, 0.333, 0.555,  Output 0.1540125
```

I need the answer to look like the above always to have 7 digits behind it.

Comment: I don't understand the relation between your inputs and outputs.

Comment: There are TONS of duplicates around here. Please search as a first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be displaying only a certain number of digits, you may want to round the result prior to display it.

```
double number = 1.23456789;
string output = Math.Round(number, 7, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString("N7")
```

The value of `output` above will be `1.2345679`.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, because i don't know the number that is going to be calculated and i can't use String.Format. Thanks man

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker ok, mark as answer if that's the case then.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0:0.0000000}", 34.5223423523542);
//  34.5223424

string.Format("{0:N7}", 34.5223423523542);
//  34.5223424
```